# Am working on a project to send bulk sms to different number and I want it to be separated by a delimiter

Tags: vb.net

Am working on a project to send bulk sms to different number  and I want it to be separated by a delimiter I mean the number and loop through before send the sms .

I try using a for loop

```
For I = 0 to txtto.text - 1
   Dim a as string 
   Txtto.text=a.split(,)
Next
```

Comment: What is in `txtto.text` ? Also, you are defining a variable `a` inside the loop of type string and then use the `split()` function on that. However, since `a` is newly DIMmed, this is an empty string.

Comment: The textbox accept phone numbers and I want to separate it with comma that’s delimiters

Comment: So, there can be multiple phone numbers in the textbox? separated by what?

Comment: @Theo by a delimeter , which means comma

Comment: Then I have a method sendmessage(the message to be sent in strong ,txt phone number.text)

Comment: Then just change the order in the loop to `a = Txtto.text.Split(",")` and dim the variable a to `Dim a() as String` because the result of Split wil be an array.

Comment: So if I change the order will I be able to send message to multiple numbers

Comment: For I as integer = 0 to txtTo.text -1  A= txtTo.text.split(“,”) next  sendsms(txtmessage.text,a(txtTo.text)) it’s telling me it resulted to an overflow

Comment: That is because you are using `txtTo.text` as array, but in fact that is a comma delimited String. To make that an array, you need to split it by the comma. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
Dim a() As String = Txtto.text.Split(New Char() {","c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

For Each phonenumber As String In a
'    Do your sendmessage() code for each number here
    sendmessage(message, phonenumber)
Next
```

The `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` makes sure you do not have empty values (phonenumbers) in the array.

Hope that helps

Comment: That arr was it the a() you declared or what

Comment: @user12105087 Yep, that was a typo